# Postgre SQL min/max inside THEN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, random, sql-insert

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO salaries (num)
SELECT
CASE random()<0.5 WHEN true THEN min(8+floor(random()*4),10))
WHEN false THEN max(8-floor(random()*4),1)) END AS num
FROM generate_series(1,1) as seq(my_id);
```

returns this error:

```
LINE 3: CASE random() < 0.5 WHEN true THEN (SELECT min(8+floor(rando...
                                                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Could you give me any hint or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you need `least()` and `greatst()` rather than `min()` and `max()` - the latter are aggregate functions, that operate over sets, not over list of values.

But I also think that your query does not do what you want. `random()` is recomputed everytime you call it. Presumably, you want a consistent value across the `case` expression, so something like:

```
insert into salaries (num)
select case when rnd < 0.5  
    then least(8 + floor(rnd * 4), 10)
    else greatest(8 - floor(rnd * 4), 1) 
end 
from (select my_id, random() rnd from generate_series(1,1) as seq(my_id)) t
```

It is *still* unclear what the purpose of `generate_series()` is the query, but I assumed that's a side effect of an oversimplified query...